# Jetpack compose breaks Room compiler

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

I created a completely fresh jetpack compose project (from the project template) with Android Studio 4.0 Canary 6 and I attempted to add room dependencies.
Here is my app-level `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.composewithroom"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-framework:0.1.0-dev03'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev03'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev03'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev03'


    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.2"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.2"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.2" // e: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.GenerationState$Builder.isIrBackend(Z)Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/codegen/state/GenerationState$Builder;

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

I get this error when I try to build it:

```
e: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.GenerationState$Builder.isIrBackend(Z)Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/codegen/state/GenerationState$Builder;
```

This can be either "fixed" by removing `kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.2"` or disabling compose `compose true`

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this or is the room database just unusable with Compose at the moment?

Comment: AFAIK, it is just unusable at the moment. There is a conflict between some of the special Kotlin magic that Compose relies upon and some annotation processors, such as Room.

Comment: Exactly -- I tried `compose = true` with `kapt "androidx.databinding"` and got the same error. Probably it's just that compose is incompatible with kapt.

Comment: Thanks @OvermindJiang, you saved a day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Should be fixed in 1.3.61... but Jetpack Compose compiler plugin is not updated.

You can find more information in the following YouTrack issue: [IR (Jetpack Compose), KAPT, Room: "AssertionError: IR backend shouldn't call KotlinTypeMapper.mapType: MainActivity"](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-34583). Last comment states that:

> The problem here is that JetPack Compose hasn't updated its internal Kotlin compiler to 1.3.61 yet. We'll see what we can do about it.

Also, the following issue in Google Issue Tracker: [Annotation processors fail when compose is enabled](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143232368)

Comment: Do You know if it has been fixed yet? Or if there is any way to make it working? I created a new project in `AS 4.2 Canary 16` added `kotlin-kapt` and room and I got an error. I think that triad everything but nothing works for me.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out after 4 hours... All I have to do was to change the Kotlin version. The newest version `1.4.20` is not working with `kapt`. When I changed to `1.4.10` it is working

Comment: @iknow You saved me hours of search... Thank you

Comment: I fixed it in Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3 by using latest `room_version = '2.3.0'` and `kotlin_version = '1.5.31'`
Make sure you use same kotlin version for compose