# Jetpack Compose compilation error with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I follow google [guidlines](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup) to setup compose in my project, this is my app-level `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.super.note"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode rootProject.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.versionName

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        useIR = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion Versions.compose
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation Kotlin.stdlib
    implementation AndroidX.coreKtx
    implementation AndroidX.appcompat
    implementation AndroidX.constraintLayout
    implementation AndroidX.recyclerView
    implementation Lifecycle.extensions
    implementation Lifecycle.livedata
    implementation Material.core
    implementation AndroidX.legacySupport
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$junit_android_version"

    //fragment androidx
    implementation AndroidX.fragment
    implementation AndroidX.fragmentKtx

    //navigation
    implementation Navigation.fragment
    implementation Navigation.uiKtx

    //Debugging
    implementation Debug.timber

    //lottie
    implementation Animation.lottie

    //Hilt DI
    implementation Di.hiltAndroid
    kapt Di.hiltCompiler
    implementation Di.hiltViewModel
    kapt Di.hiltAndroidX

    //compose
    implementation Compose.core
    implementation Compose.material
    implementation Compose.tooling

    implementation project(":domain")
    implementation project(":data")
}
```

I get this error when I try build it:

```
e: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.GenerationState$Builder.isIrBackend(Z)Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/codegen/state/GenerationState$Builder;
```

I use Firebase, hilt and corutine and build project with Android Studio 4.2 Canary.

Does anyone have idea to fix this or I can’t use firebase and google play corutine with compose at the moment? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59277354/jetpack-compose-breaks-room-compiler

Comment: Thanks, but in my project I don't use room database